# Is there any chance to set fractional scale on Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics Controller?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, display-settings, integrated-graphics, screenresolution

I connect to a Ubuntu 22.04.2 node in a cloud through VNC. I would like to set a fractional scale of the display. But whenever I set the Scale and click Apply button in Displays settings, the Scale goes back to an integer multiple of 100%.

The results of `sudo lshw -C display` is

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics Controller
       vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 04
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=mgag200 latency=0 maxlatency=32 mingnt=16 resolution=1024,768
       resources: irq:16 memory:91000000-91ffffff memory:92808000-9280bfff memory:92000000-927fffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

So, given this hardware, is there any chance to set fractional scale like 150%? If yes, how? Thanks.